# How to get to Heroku Public directort from con the console

Tags: heroku, console

I am trying to create a file (csv) and put it on the pubic directory so i can downloaded it 
I have

```
Model.all.to_csv > I_need_this_path
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

well to start off, try to type this at the command line

```
heroku run bash
```

from there on it's all unix scripting...